# Java gRPC client cannot invoke server

Tags: java, keycloak, grpc-java

I am currently trying to implement a custom provider for keycloak. This provider needs to invoke a gRPC service. However I can't seem to make it work, and I don't really see why. I tried to invoke the gPRC service with multiple clients and it worked, however when I try to invoke it from my custom REST endpoint it gives me this error:

```
 2023-03-07 17:06:29,101 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (grpc-default-executor-0) Uncaught server error: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
   at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:539)
   at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:487)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:576)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:757)
   at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:736)
   at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
   at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newConnectException0(Errors.java:153)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.handleConnectErrno(Errors.java:128)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.connect(Socket.java:313)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect0(AbstractEpollChannel.java:773)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:758)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDomainSocketChannel.doConnect(EpollDomainSocketChannel.java:87)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.connect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:600)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1342)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:533)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:54)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.connect(WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler.java:157)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:548)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1000(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:61)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$9.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:538)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:391)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
   at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
   ... 1 more
```

As my provider requires external dependencies that are not present in Keycloak's classpath I am using the maven assembly plugin to create a JAR file that contains all the dependencies. What I found out is maybe it can be causing this error according to this comment:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/9367#issuecomment-1183715933

In the with-depencies jar file I also have the META-INF/services/io.grpc.NameResolverProvider with the content io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.UdsNameResolverProvider, and according to the comment this is not good. I tried removing this file from the jar file, but it resulted in failure, as this time it did not find any registered implementations for the io.grpc.NameResolverProvider. I don't know what I need tho replace this with to make it work, I cannot seem to find any docs on these NameResolverProviders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by creating an assembly descriptor in `src/assembly/assembly.xml` with the following content:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.1 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.1.xsd">
    <id>with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <containerDescriptorHandlers>
        <containerDescriptorHandler>
            <handlerName>metaInf-services</handlerName>
        </containerDescriptorHandler>
    </containerDescriptorHandlers>
</assembly>
```

Then added this to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
    <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
</configuration>
```